# Add Pandas column values in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Python code (not 100% complete):

```
labels = []
for i in range(0, len(test)):
    name = test.iloc[i]['name']
    s = name.split('.')
    label_name = s[0]
    label = label_names.index(label_name)
    id = int(s[1])
    labels.append(label)
test['label'] = labels
```

The last statement generates a "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." warning.

Is there a better way to create the new column 'label' in the dataframe?

Comment: You certainly want to use `test["label"]=test["name"].apply(fun)`, where `fun(name)` is a function that takes a `name` and return a `label`.

Comment: That doesn't mean your code is wrong, its only a warning. If at some point in the future you only want to get rid of the warning (not your question thats why I'm commenting) you could just type  "pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None" after importing pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_function(input):
   name = input
   s = name.split('.')
   label_name = s[0]
   label = label_names.index(label_name)
   id = int(s[1])

   return label

test['label'] = test['name'].apply(lambda x: my_function(x))
```